# How can I add the QtSql library in Qt creator?

Tags: qt, qt4, qt-creator

when I compile the codes which has database connection, there's an error like,

```
QtSql: No such file or directory
```

I suppose that the sql library must be in Qt, but I dont have any idea why an error occured ?
what to do for enable the database's libraries?
Can you help me please, thanks

Comment: also how to add this LIB to .pro file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [QtSql](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtsql-index.html) documentation,

In your `.pro` file you have to add,

```
QT += sql
```

AFAIK there is no separate library to be included for SQL module. It's enough if you add the above line to your `.pro` file.

Since you are not aware of adding libraries,

From [qmake](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#libs) documentation, libraries can be added by using `LIBS` keyword.

An example from the same documentation itself..

```
unix:LIBS += -lmath -L/usr/local/lib
win32:LIBS += c:\mylibs\math.lib
```